# Use attributes in heuristic

Tags: python, networkx

I want to use a heuristic for A* in networkx, but I can't find out how to access node attributes in the heuristic (I need them for my heuristic). How can I access node attributes in a heuristic function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `G` is your graph, then the attribute `key` of node `n` can be accessed with

```
G.node[n][key]
```

---

If `G` is not in an outer scope of the heuristic function already, then to make `G` accessible to the heuristic function, use a closure:

```
def make_heuristic(G):
    def heuristic(a, b):
        a_attr, b_attr = [G.node[n][key] for n in (a, b)]
        ...
    return heuristic

nx.astar_path(G,start,end,make_heuristic(G))
```

Comment: The heuristic function only takes two attributes that are nodes.